# duplicate record querying multiple table rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this sql to query from different tables

```
SELECT * 
FROM `person` 
  LEFT JOIN person_address 
    ON person_address.person_id=person.person_id 
  LEFT JOIN address_type 
    ON address_type.address_type_id=person_address.address_type_id
```

it return this data, [image]

It's really tedious to achieve this json format

```
//json
[{
  "person_id":"1",
  "full_name":"john",
  "scores": [{
    "address_type":"billing",
    "address_name":"Spain"
  },{
    "address_type":"home",
    "address_name":"USA"
  }]
}]
```

I should fix my sql query or it's that tedious I have to do manual looping using PHP to produce the json?

Tried DISTINCT 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XlQX.png

doesn't seems to work

Comment: What is your effort so far? Show us your code and current output.

Comment: Is it a many to many relationship? if so that is normal. its a `Cartesian product`  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product  You'll have to use `DISTINCT`

Comment: @ino spent an hour fixing sql query.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix DISTINCT is the same with GROUP_BY?

Comment: No, it is not the same.  Group By is aggregation, Distinct is Unique.

Comment: If you had an auto increment ID in the bridge table, and returned it you would probably see a different ID there.  It's sort of like multiplying, the rows.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix tried it, I only got id returned back.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix https://i.imgur.com/tZFvKAD.png

Comment: @ino want to help? https://i.imgur.com/tZFvKAD.png

Comment: sorry I don't do images. I would suggest using a DB fiddle like this one  https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: `it return this data`, So it returns an image of the Relationship schema?  That's what I see there.`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sql, you'll just have to build the json around the data generated so checking "if my person is the same keep adding to the scores array" as it's a 1-many relationship. Short answer, you're already doing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

here is a supper simplified version of what I am talking about.

Given this schema ( simple Many To Many )

```
CREATE TABLE a(
  id INT(10)
);

INSERT INTO a (id)VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO a (id)VALUES(2);

CREATE TABLE b(
  a_id INT(10),
  c_id INT(10)
);

INSERT INTO b (a_id,c_id)VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO b (a_id,c_id)VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO b (a_id,c_id)VALUES(2,1);
INSERT INTO b (a_id,c_id)VALUES(2,2);

CREATE TABLE c(
  id INT(10),
  val VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO c (id,val)VALUES(1,'one');
```

Now if you run this query:

```
SELECT
 c.val AS c_val
FROM
 a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
JOIN c ON b.c_id = c.id
WHERE
 c.id = 1;
```

You will get this result

```
'one'
'one'
```

But if you run this query

```
SELECT
  b.a_id,
  b.c_id,
  c.val AS c_val
FROM
  a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
JOIN c ON b.c_id = c.id;
```

Which is just display all you will see this

```
a_id  | c_id |  c_val
1    |   1   |   one
2    |   1   |   one
```

AS seen in this DB fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fZnRCSXeu3wYVFzn4NBjC5/0

This is pretty clear why in this simple example, but in a more complicated case it may not be as clear.  This is especially true if the where clause matches multiple rows in the last table.

Besides that you should have the key in the bridge table ( b in the above example ) set as a compound primary key on the id's from the other 2 tables.

Now the way to fix the first query is to simply add `DISTINCT` to it

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 c.val AS c_val
FROM
 a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
JOIN c ON b.c_id = c.id
WHERE
 c.id = 1;
```

Now the output is

```
'one'
```

AS seen in the last query in this updated fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fZnRCSXeu3wYVFzn4NBjC5/1

Comment: seems like my query doesn't have a problem, the duplicated one column is just fine. But I still have to do the manipulation to produce the nested json.

Comment: I would think that should be obvious, as MySQL only returns flat data.  So either you do one query then nest them in PHP or you select the top level, then as you build that you select the nested data.  I prefer the first method.  I was thinking duplicate meant duplicate data.  In which case I was showing a common misunderstanding of Many to Many relationships.  Where you can appear to have duplicates, but they are not "truly" duplicates.

Comment: I was working on nosql, then I have to do php and mysqli, it's a pain.